# Java clone on variable of interface type

Tags: java, interface, clone

I'm a bit of a Java N00B, but I am majorly confused about clone.

Consider the following incorrect class

```
class blah {
   public blah(Collection<Integer> c){
       member_collection = c.clone(); //the clone here is defensive
   }
   private final Collection<Integer> member_collection;
}
```

I think what I want to do is clear.

I understand why the clone() symbol is not found: clone is not a public method in any possibly Collection.  However, in any concrete class I would want to use it is, and I want to just tell the compiler that.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to clone a generic collection, but the tutorials I have looked at only explain why you cannot clone a Collection, not how to get around the problem.  I have tried hacky stuff with getClass() and casting, but those usually require me to make ugly try-catch blocks and it's difficult to ensure exactly one initialization (the pointer member_collection) is final!

What I'd really like to do is somehow put that information into the type somehow.  Is there a nice way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off copying like so:

```
public class Blah {
    private final Collection<Integer> collection;

    public Blah(Collection<Integer> collection) {
        this.collection = new ArrayList<Integer>(collection);
    }
}
```

Or like so:

```
public class Blah {
    private final Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Blah(Collection<Integer> collection) {
        this.collection.addAll(collection);
    }
}
```

This is the same as what you're trying and guarantees that any order of the given `Collection` is preserved.

**Edit:** If you absolutely need it to be the same implementation as the one given to you and you don't want to rethink your design, then you can do some of the hacky reflection stuff and put it in a `static` method.

```
public class Blah {
    private final Collection<Integer> collection;

    public Blah(Collection<Integer> collection) {
        this.collection = clone(collection);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T clone(T t) {
        try {
            Method cloneMethod = t.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clone");
            return (T) cloneMethod.invoke(t);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO Log ex
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Must of the concrete collections implement `clone` as a public method, so this should work for most of them. It will be `null` for the ones that don't. You may want to just rethrow whatever exception you get instead.

Comment: but what if I want collection to not be an ArrayList?

Comment: @JosephVictor Then change `new ArrayList` to whatever you want it to be. All of the collection implementations (that I know of, anyway) have a copy constructor, including those such as [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: But why would you?  If you don't care what type of collection the input is, use an `ArrayList`.  If you do, use another specific implementation type.  Wanting to "copy whatever implementation you're passed" is probably an indication that there's something wrong _there._

Comment: If you insist. I've updated my answer. I agree with @LouisWasserman that if you care about the implementation being passed to you, you probably have other design issues on your hands.

Answer (score 2):

As your are a Java novice, I am sorry to tell you that `clone()` and `Cloneable` in Java are broken and it's not a good idea to rely on them. However, if you just want to `clone()` the damn thing, you can just:

1. include [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) in your project
2. Make use of `ObjectUtils.clone()`/`ObjectUtils.cloneIfPossible()` (not strongly typed but reasonably safe).

Using commons-lang is not a bad idea anyway, as it contains a lot of utility "should be in the JRE" classes and methods, and it is pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `member_collection = new ArrayList<Integer>(c)`.

This will create a shallow copy.